# error 1004: The RowHeight property of the Range object can not be set. (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, row-height

The following error message is displayed as soon as my inputfield contains more than 1000 characters:

> error 1004: The RowHeight property of the Range object can not be set.

When I debug the code, on the following position is the error:

```
Sheets("Tab").Cells(142, 2).RowHeight = Sheets("Tab").Range("F" & "142").Rows.RowHeight + 4
```

The result should be a generated PDF file that contains a table with 2 columns.

Answer (score 2):

Cells do not have row height. Rows have row height. Thus, you need something like this:

```
Rows("142:142").rowheight =Rows("142:142").rowheight + 4
```